# This c# code smells..seems like there should be a cleaner way to write this

Tags: c#, string

Anyone have any ideas to clean this up?

```
 public string FullName
    {
        get
        {
            var fullName = new StringBuilder();
            if (FirstName.Length > 0)
                fullName.Append(FirstName);
            if (LastName.Length > 0)
            {
                if (fullName.Length > 0)
                    fullName.Append(" " + LastName);
                else
                    fullName.Append(LastName);
            }
            return fullName.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: StringBuilder is a bit overkill for this.

Comment: I feel like I'm getting to the point where if I never hear "code smell" again it won't be a moment too soon.   (it is actually possible to look at code and evaluate empircally the cost/benefit of a given algorithm without having to sniff around and use your intuition)

Comment: Linqsturbation: `return new[] { FirstName, LastName }.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)).Join(" ")`

Comment: +1 to siride for "linqstrubation". I love that word, but can't stand the practice. To each their own, I suppose.

Comment: @CharlieKilian like anything, Linq is really nice in some situations and really awful in others. This is one of those situations. That's why it's a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @siride I'm probably just sour grapes because I'm not very good at it yet. ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
FullName = string.format("{0} {1}",FirstName,LastName).Trim()
```

Comment: The trim removes trailing spaces if LastName is empty

Comment: @EdS. that's not what the trim does.

Comment: Trim takes care of leading spaces too (in case of FirstName empty, LastName not empty) btw.

Answer (score 1):

First off, using a `StringBuilder` here seems unnecessary as you know exactly how many concatenations may be performed (4) and, unless it has been shown to be a bottleneck, serves only to clutter the code.

You could make it much more simple by using `String.Format()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
public string FullName
{
    get
    {
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(FirstName) ? LastName 
            : string.IsNullOrEmpty(LastName) ? FirstName : FirstName + " " + LastName;
    }
}
```